# How to modify content before writing to DB in Apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to add a field to each piece of content that gets created in Apostrophe that takes a value from the local.js file and adds it as an attribute to the record in mongo. For a variety of reasons, I do not want users to control the value of this because the value will be the same for each piece of content created in a particular instance of Apostrophe. I've tried adding the attribute to req.data on beforeInsert without any luck--I see it when I console.log req.data but it never makes it to the database. Where is the appropriate place to do this?

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

You want to attach the custom data to `piece` in `beforeInsert`, not req.data

In your `lib/modules/foo-piece/index.js`

```
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.beforeInsert = function (req, piece, options, callback) {
      piece.foo = 'something nice'
      return callback(null);
    };
  }
```